# SELECT works, but not to create VIEW

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, geospatial

I have the following SELECT which does what I want, but would prefer to use it to create a VIEW.  When I try it though, I get an error about the remote function .STEquals not being allowed.

```
SELECT 
    [CadData].dbo.CleanLines.FeatId as LINEid,
    [CadData].dbo.CleanLines.Geom as LINEgeom,
    CleanLines.Geom.STEndPoint() as ENDPT,
    CleanLines.Geom.STStartPoint() as STPT,
    start_point.ObjectId,
    start_point.Name as STPTName,
    start_point.[Description] as STPTdesc,
    end_point.Name as EndPointName,
    end_point.[Description] as ENDPTdesc

FROM CadData.dbo.CleanLines 
  JOIN [CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint start_point
    ON CleanLines.Geom.STStartPoint().STEquals(start_point.Geometry) = 1
  JOIN [CadData].Survey.SurveyPoint end_point 
    ON CleanLines.Geom.STEndPoint().STEquals(end_point.Geometry) = 1
  order by LINEid asc
```

Comment: is STEquals the userdefined function u created on same database?

Comment: Why don't you create the view in the `CadData` database (or at least create *a* view there, and then this view can reference it).

Comment: Rather than view, use stored procedure ;)

Comment: STEquals is predefined spatial function;

Comment: Aaron - I am trying to create the view in the CadData database. I run the Select in the SQL Server Management Studio for testing, and thought I could copy/paste it to create a view.

Comment: Perhaps to add some perspective, I am importing cad data which includes the properties of geometry (e.g, radius of arcs, bearings, lengths, etc.)  I am also importing point coordinates that I need to relate to the cad data (either as endpoints, or center points). Once the data is correlated, I want to export the data in a specific format, and a separate (external) process will update the point coordinates.  Then, the points will be imported back into the DB, the geometry will be re-created using the new coordinates and then if required, the geometry can be used to re-create the cad data.